# Razor Helpers sharing html problem with code blocks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I guess what I want to do is "chain" my data down so that it ends up looking the same.
All my html must be wrapped in some form of

```
<fieldset class="" data-role="">
```

So what I have is a helper that prints the various forms. One would be a label:

```
<fieldset data-role="@role">
    <label>@Html.Raw(label)</label>
</fieldset>
```

Now when I have multiple types of labels, and one includes being a code block. When it is a 
simple piece of text, like "First Name" I do:

```
@FieldSet.Label("First Name")
```

But when I have a code block such as:

```
<b>some text</b>
<p>some other text (some time frame - some time frame)
```

It becomes complicated to use this:

```
@FieldSet.Label("<b>" + Model.Text1 + "</b><p>" + Model.Text2 + 
    " (" + Model.Time1 + " - " + Model.Time2 +")</p>")
```

**What I want it a solution that looks something like this:**

```
@FieldSet.Label(@<text>
<b>@Model1.Text1</b>
<p>@Model.Text2 (@Model.Time1 - @Model.Time2)</p>
</text>)
```

I read somewhere this was possible, but I cannot find the article. I could be completely misled, but I really don't want to have a single piece of HTML in the code behind and I want to utilize the razor syntax, not string concatenation.

Comment: I don't like any of the solutions even though they were correct answers. I am going to start a new thread for "Best practices" instead, maybe I'll get an answer I can use there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this articles from Phil Haack

- http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx
- http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/14/a-better-razor-foreach-loop.aspx

You could:

**Write as an extension method to a strongly-typed HtmlHelper:**

```
public static class RazorExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult Label<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Func<T, HelperResult> template) {
        return new HelperResult(writer => {
            writer.Write("<label>");
            template(helper.ViewData.Model).WriteTo(writer);
            writer.Write("</label>");
        });
    }
}
```

So you could write

```
@Html.Label(@<text><span>@Model.Item1<span><strong>@Model.Item2</strong></text>)
```

**Pass Model as a parameter to your helper method**

```
public static class FieldSet
{
    public static HelperResult Label<T>(this T model, Func<T, HelperResult> template) {
        return new HelperResult(writer => {
            writer.Write("<label>");
            template(model).WriteTo(writer);
            writer.Write("</label>");
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@FieldSet.Label(Model, @<div><span>@Model.UserName</span><strong>@Model.FullName</strong><p>@Model.Description</p></div>)
```

Comment: good reads but still having issues actually making it work. their implementations don't support sharing code. just changes in looping, which is not my problem.

Comment: seems like I'd have to use dynamic objects, also a bad thing. I'd have to have my helper accept a Func<> and my TModel and pass the model to the Func<> and do item in replace of the Model in the cshtml

Comment: Is this what you expected me to end up with?
`@helper Label(Func<dynamic, HelperResult> template, dynamic model, DataRole role = DataRole.fieldcontain)
{
    @Label(role, template.Invoke(model).ToString());
}
@FieldSetHelper.Label(@<text>My Response: @item.Answer (@item.AnsweredOn)</text>, question)`

Comment: Not necessarily dynamic, you can make a helper for a HtmlHelper<T> or pass a Model as an argument to your helper.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at how the `@Html.BeginForm` is implemented.

Create a class that implements IDisposable, and that writes to the Response stream directly:

Your code could look like this (entered by head, not tested):

```
class FieldSet : IDisposable {
     public FieldSet(string label) {
          // TODO: Encode label on line below
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<fieldset><label =\"{0}\"", label));
     }

    public void Dispose() {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</fieldset>");
    }
}

static class FieldSetExtionsions {
    public static FieldSet FieldSet(this HtmlHelper html, string label) {
        return new FieldSet(label);
    }
}
```

The usage will be:

```
@using (Html.FieldSet("your label")) {
     <div>
         Your razor code goes here
     </div>
}
```

Comment: This definitely seems like the best approach to me; after all, a fieldset is supposed to encapsulate a set of fields.